# Apache Camel: Call route again or dynamic routes

Tags: jms, apache-camel, jboss6.x

I'm using **JBoss Fuse 6.1.0** with **Camel 2.10.0.redhat-60024**.
The list of routes are already known. For example: `#start, #step1, #step2, #step3, #finish`.

But I don't know sequence. Or sometimes some route may not be needed. I will know that only at `#router` route (please, see below code).

For example: `#start, #step2, #step1, #step3, #finish.` or `#start, #step1, #step3, #finish.` or etc.

But **Camel 2.10.0** doesn't have such thing as `dynamicRouter`. I decided to do something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...
<camelContext id="blueprintContext" trace="true"
    xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route id="start">
        <from uri="..." />
        <to uri="vm:router" />
    </route>
    <route id="router">
        <from uri="vm:router" />
        <bean ref="stepGenerator" method="nextStep" />
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${header.step} contains 'step1'</simple>
                <to uri="vm:step1" />
            </when>
            <when>
                <simple>${header.step} contains 'step2'</simple>
                <to uri="vm:step2" />
            </when>
            <when>
                <simple>${header.step} contains 'step3'</simple>
                <to uri="vm:step3" />
            </when>
            <when>
                <simple>${header.step} contains 'finish'</simple>
                <to uri="vm:finish" />
            </when>
        </choice>
    </route>
    <route id="step1">
        <from uri="vm:step1" />
        <log message="Step 1 started." />
        <!-- Some logic -->
        <to uri="vm:router" />
    </route>
    <route id="step2">
        <from uri="vm:step2" />
        <log message="Step 2 started." />
        <!-- Some logic -->
        <to uri="vm:router" />
    </route>
    <route id="step3">
        <from uri="vm:step3" />
        <log message="Step 3 started." />
        <!-- Some logic -->
        <to uri="vm:router" />
    </route>
    <route id="finish">
        <from uri="vm:finish" />
        <log message="Finished!" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Imagine that we have next sequence: `#start, #step1, #step2, #step3, #finish`. If you to try to run this will be stopped at `#start -> #router-> #step1`.

In `#step1` `<to uri="vm:router" />` not working. If you call route twice it will not work. Why? 
How can I solve this situation in **Camel 2.10.0**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the camel website](http://camel.apache.org/dynamic-router.html) the dynamic Router pattern was introduced in 
Version 2.5. I am sure that will work for you...

Comment: Ohh. I had an old XSD schema in blueprint that told me about non existent 'dynamic Route' tag. Thank you for your vigilance!